# LOOP from index has syntax error Type "TDLINE" has no structure

Tags: loops, abap

I have an index stored in a variable `lv_index`. I need to get lines from the table where the index of a line is greater than `lv_index`. I tried this with no success.

Example:

```
DATA:
        lt_text       TYPE TABLE OF tline-tdline,
        lv_text       TYPE tline-tdline.
.
.
.
LOOP AT lt_text INTO lv_text WHERE row > lv_index.
  * some code here
ENDLOOP.
```

I get this error:

> Type "TDLINE" has no structure so it  doesn't have attribute "ROW"

Can someone tell me what should I write instead of `row` to make it work right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example:

```
LOOP AT lt_text INTO lv_text FROM lv_index.
    * some code
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: `FROM` is >= lv_index ... use `FROM lv_index + 1.` in our case

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can read index of current position from system structure SY. Indexes are in SY-TABIX and SY-INDX fields.

Answer (score 0):

or you can create a work area for the table and use loop to get the grater values

    `DATA:
        lt_text       TYPE TABLE OF tline-tdline,
        lv_text       TYPE tline-tdline,
        lwa_table     TYPE lt_text.
    Loop AT lwa_table.
ENDLOOP`

.